# Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem how to get path to local file

Tags: outlook, add-in

Is there any option to get path to local msg/eml file?
For example: User opens file from local drive. My inspector wrapper should detect is this file located on a specific folder.
Have tried MAPIFolder but it's returns only outlook specific locations like Inbox.

```
item = (TOutlookItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;
var mail = item as MailItem;
var folder = mail.Parent as MAPIFolder;
var path = folder.FullFolderPath;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that - Outlook always creates a temporary message in the default store and imports the EML / MSG file prior to displaying the message.

The best you can do is check that `MailItem.EmtryID == ""` and `MailItem.Saved == true` to detect such a message.